# js regex not support lookbehind how to implement this?

Tags: javascript, regex

`a = "1+2-3*4/5+(6+7^2)"`
I want to get the pure number but not include second 2.
Because second 2 is exponent. It's fixed. I don't want it.
I written a regex.
`var myRegx = (?<=[\+\-\*\/\(\^])\d+`
JS don't support lookbehind.

Who can help me?
`var r = a.match(yourRegx)`
I want get=>
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show some additional sample inputs? E.g., can `^` appear anywhere, or can there be more than one `^`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break this into three separate functions. first replace any exponents, second get any numbers from the string. Finally map all the strings to numbers.

```js
const a = '1+2-3*4/5+(6+7^2)'
const r = a.replace(/\^\d+/g).match(/\d+/g).map(Number)

console.log(r)
```

Using match has a flaw of not returning an empty array if there are no matches, so the above code will throw an error if you don't have any numbers in your string. If you need type safety and error handling you could use a functional pattern like this.

```js
const a = '1+2-3*4/5+(6+7^2)'
const b = 'word'

const extractNumbers = x =>
  [x].map(x => x.replace(/\^\d+/g))
     .map(x => x.match(/\d+/g))
     .map(x => x != null ? x.map(Number) : x)
     .pop() 

console.log(extractNumbers(a))
console.log(extractNumbers(b))
```

Comment: Probably should be `/\^\d+/g`.